# How can I give myself a nickname?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why can't I give myself a nickname?

I have already tried about 50 names. I have tried many American names and some nonsense names.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a quick search before you post a question. This has been asked a few times already.

Comment: Try "cantfindname7242"

Answer (score 0):

The trainer nickname is very poorly worded. It is actually your in-game username and thus has to be unique. So a nickname like Bob or Mike would most likely already be taken.

Comment: This is wrong, I tried the same name 3 times in a row and was allowed it the third time. I think it is either a server issue, or the name is taken. (I'm not sure but i would assume they also block a number of words)